# Video recording and editing for game promo video

Tags: marketing, video, game-recording, screen-recording

I would like to screen record a beta of an RPG I've created. The format will be narration over video with the ability to edit. It's an indie game I'm marketing, so the video quality and narration need to be semi-professional.

I'm curious as to which video production packages are of good enough quality to accomplish this without breaking the bank (free is the best!). If there are no good packages, then separate software recommendations for screen recording, editing, and narration would be helpful!

Notes:

- I have a Mac
- I would rather do video recording first, then narration later with an overlay
- I've used Quicktime in the past, not sure if there was something better
- This video is for my Kickstarter campaign

Comment: I know Lynda.com uses [Camtasia](https://www.techsmith.com/video-editor.html), it works great for this purpose, but it's not free :/.

Comment: @Byte56 I've used Camtasia before. Pretty great!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I go through the process:

1) Record footage via Open Broadcast Software (OBS). It's free, works pretty well, is very customizable and is supported on Mac (although, never used it on Mac so don't know how different it is). I personally prefer it over Xtreme Broadcaster.

2) Edit footage in Adobe Premiere + Adobe After Effects. The combination is super effective and can get you anywhere as long as you can imagine what you want. Both work great on Mac. The drawback is that it isn't free (about $20/mo for student version) and the learning curve can be intimidating.

3) Audacity is what I use for voice recording. It's simple and supports most of the features you can think of. It should also be available on Mac.